# How to show Japanese characters in Mac OS X Terminal?

Tags: macos, unicode, localization, character-encoding, lexical-analysis

So I'm running MeCab (http://mecab.sourceforge.net/#download) to word-segment and do morpho-analysis of Japanese sentences. However, when I run the program, I see abracadabra due to some encoding issues in Mac OS X Terminal. I googled the topic, added Dfile.encoding option, added the following 3 lines in .inputrc:

```
set convert-meta off
set meta-flag on
set output-meta on
```

Nothing works. Any ideas how to show Japanese characters in Mac OS X Terminal? Here's the output of the run of the program test.java:

```
env DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=. /usr/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 test
0.98pre3
å¤  ̾»ì,°ìÈÌ,*,*,*,*,*
ª郎ã µ­¹æ,°ìÈÌ,*,*,*,*,*
¯ä  ̾»ì,¸Çͭ̾»ì,Áȿ¥,*,*,*,*
º郎にこのæ  µ­¹æ,°ìÈÌ,*,*,*,*,*
¬ã  ̾»ì,¥µÊÑÀÜ³,*,*,*,*,*
    µ­¹æ,°ìÈÌ,*,*,*,*,*
æ¸  ̾»ì,°ìÈÌ,*,*,*,*,*
¡ã  µ­¹æ,³ç
    BOS/EOS,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*
å   ̾»ì,°ìÈÌ,*,*,*,*
ª郎  µ­¹æ,°ìÈÌ,*,*,*
¯   ̾»ì,¸Çͭ̾»ì,Áȿ¥,*,*
º郎にこ    µ­¹æ,°ìÈÌ,*,*,*
¬   ̾»ì,¥µÊÑÀÜ³,*,*,*,
    µ­¹æ,°ìÈÌ,*,*,*
æ   ̾»ì,°ìÈÌ,*,*,*,*
¡   µ­¹æ,³ç¸̳«,*,*,*,*
    µ­¹æ,°ìÈÌ,*,*,*
    BOS/EOS,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*
EOS
```

Comment: What is the output when you run the following command: 'mecab -D'

Comment: I'm surprised it doesn't work.  I have a UTF-8 text file (saved from TextEdit) with Japanese text -- `file myfile.txt` returns `UTF-8 Unicode English text` (well, close enough!) -- and if I `cat myfile.txt` it looks perfect in Terminal.  If you pipe it to `hexdump`, do you get the UTF-8 bytes you expect?

Comment: Yeah, actually one of the reasons I bought a Mac was because it was able to print Japanese characters on a terminal without having to do anything (compared to Windows where it was literally impossible without drastic changes), the fact that there are some Japanese characters in the text above proves that this aspect is technically working - it's likely something else in the process is screwing up exactly what's printed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have thought that this was the default setting, but you could try selecting "Unicode (UTF-8)" as the Character encoding from **Preferences...**, **Settings**, **Advanced**, **International**. If this is already set, you may want to confirm that your program output is actually encoded in UTF-8. It could be Shift-JIS, EUC, or even UTF-16? In that case, try enabling those encodings from **Preferences...**, **Encodings**.

Answer (score 1):

After this

```
% cd mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-xxxx
% ./configure --with-charset=utf8
% sudo make
% sudo make install
```

the output of 'mecab -D' is

```
% cd mecab-java-0.98pre3
% mecab -D
filename:    /usr/local/lib/mecab/dic/ipadic/sys.dic
version:    102
charset:    utf8
type:    0
size:    392126
left size:    1316
right size:    1316
```

Here's the output of running the test program.

```
bash-3.2$ env DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=. /usr/bin/java test
0.98pre3
??    ??,????,??,?,*,*,??,???,???
?    ??,???,*,*,*,*,?,?,?
??    ??,????,??,?,*,*,??,???,???
?    ??,???,??,*,*,*,?,?,?
??    ???,*,*,*,*,*,??,??,??
?    ??,??,*,*,*,*,?,??,??
?    ??,???,??,*,*,*,?,?,?
??    ??,??,*,*,?????,???,??,???,???
?    ???,*,*,*,????,???,?,?,?
?    ??,??,*,*,*,*,?,?,?
EOS

    BOS/EOS,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*
??    ??,????,??,?,*,*,??,???,???
?    ??,???,*,*,*,*,?,?,?
??    ??,????,??,?,*,*,??,???,???
?    ??,???,??,*,*,*,?,?,?
??    ???,*,*,*,*,*,??,??,??
?    ??,??,*,*,*,*,?,??,??
?    ??,???,??,*,*,*,?,?,?
??    ??,??,*,*,?????,???,??,???,???
?    ???,*,*,*,????,???,?,?,?
?    ??,??,*,*,*,*,?,?,?
    BOS/EOS,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*
EOS
```

What am I missing to make encoding work?

P/S: all Japanese encodings are enabled at Preferences - Encodings in Terminal, encoding (Preferences - Settings - Advanced - International) in Mac OS X Terminal is UTF-8.

Comment: OK, finally I see Japanese characters. Thank you, guys, for help! I wouldn't have figured this out on my own.

Comment: Perhaps you could start marking the correct answers to your questions? Looks like a lot of people may have helped you out.

Comment: @buruzaemon: the most important step was './configure --with-charset=utf8' in mecab-ipadic. The reason Terminal wasn't printing Japanese characters after reconfiguration of mecab-ipadic is that instead of 'env DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=. /usr/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 test' I was doing 'env DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=. /usr/bin/java test'. Thank you all! Now as I have the part-of-speech figured out, it's time to move on to the next stage of the project :P